# Custom size of TTF font in title

Tags: fonts, context

I installed a font from .ttf via LuaTeX (`mtxrun --script font --reload`) but I am not able to use it in title with my own size.

I have this:

`\definefontfamily[Signika][ss][signika]`

and I am trying to set this font to title:

`\setuphead[section][style=Signika]`

This works, but I want to change the size. I found out I can do that with `\switchtobodyfont`:

`\setuphead[section][style={\switchtobodyfont[Signika,18pt]}`

But that does not work... Font and font size simply does not change.

When I try defining font like:

`\definefont[myfont][Signika at 18pt]`

It outputs this:

```
fonts           > defining > unknown font 'Signika', loading aborted
fonts           > defining > unable to define 'Signika' as 'myfont--0'
fonts           > defining > font with asked name 'Signika' is not found using lookup 'file'
```

Can I somehow set font size for title?

Comment: You have to create a minimal example for your problem.

Comment: I somehow edited post to be more specific.

Comment: Do you get usefull information with `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all signika`.

Comment: I have managed this problem, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `\switchtobodyfont` doesn't work where you forgot in the example the right bracket (`]`) for the second argument of `\setuphead`.

Comment: That's mistype I made when I was writing question.

Answer (score 1):

I just have realised that `\definefont` requires `fontname` of font not `identifier` neither `familyname`.

You can find this information running `mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern=signika`. Instead of signika select name of your font.